# Problemas com a estrutura de links no MVC

Tags: php, html, html5, mvc

Estou trabalhando em um projeto MVC e estou com problemas no redirecionamento das páginas. O projeto se baseia em *controllers* e *actions*, que tenho as devidas funções que chamam esses arquivos e chamam seus métodos, no caso, as *actions*.

Esse é o HTML do menu:

```
<li class="button"><a href="">To view this page in English</a></li>
<li class="button"><a href="apresentacao">Apresentação</a></li>
<li class="button"><a href="objetivos">Objetivos</a></li>
<li class="button"><a href="participantes">Participantes</a></li>
<li class="button"><a href="pesquisa">Pesquisas e Projetos</a></li>
```

Quando o URL está assim:

```
http://localhost/pasta_raiz/   ou
http://localhost/pasta_raiz/index
```

Ao clicar em um link no menu, por exemplo, apresentação o redirecionamento ocorre corretamente para o seguinte link:

```
http://localhost/pasta_raiz/apresentacao
```

Porém quando os URLs estão com o *action* explicito, ou seja:

```
http://localhost/pasta_raiz/index/index
```

Ao clicar no *link* apresentação, sou encaminhado para:

```
http://localhost/pasta_raiz/index/apresentacao
```

Sendo que o correto seria:

```
http://localhost/pasta_raiz/apresentacao
```

E quando coloco nos endereços `href="/apresentacao"` sou encaminhado para:

```
http://localhost/apresentacao
```

Resultando em um *page not found*. Não sei o que fazer, o que pode estar errado?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

você precisa definir uma função com a URL base do seu aplicativo.
por exemplo:

```
<?php

function site_url($uri = null) {
   if($uri) {
      return "http://localhost/pasta_raiz/$uri";
   }

   return "http://localhost/pasta_raiz";
}
```

assim em cada link que você for criar, você chama por:

`<a href="<?php echo site_url('apresentacao'); ?>">apresentacao</a>`

oque acontece, quando você passa uma url no `<a href="apresentacao">aprensentação</a>`, o navegador sempre irá recuperar a pagina atual + o link que esta na tag `href=""`.
para resolver isso você precisa passar a url completa, utilizando uma função simples como eu citei acima resolve o problema.!

Answer (score 4):

A função abaixo é uma adaptação a minha [Request::getBaseUrl()](https://github.com/nextframework/next/blob/dev/HTTP/Request.php#L396) e funciona quase do mesmo jeito que a proposta pelo @Wellington mas usa variáveis do servidor para a primeira metade imutável da string final:

```
function getBaseUrl( $basepath = NULL ) {
    return sprintf( 'http://%s/%s/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $basepath );
}

var_dump( getBaseUrl( 'somedir' ) . 'myfile.php' );
```

Resulta em:

```
http://localhost:8080/somedir/myfile.php
```

Por usar a variável de servidor **$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']**, caso haja alguma porta, como é o caso do servidor interno do PHP 5.4+, ela já é automaticamente adicionado, dispensando modificações.

Comment: Não seria bacana colocar um `rtrim` para poder normalizar o número de barras? `rtrim(sprintf( 'http://%s/%s/', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], $basepath ), '/');`

Comment: Como eu fiz uma mera adaptação quando havia respondido, deixei o mais simples possível. Se você verificar o código-fonte original do link verá que têm outras coisas mais além de um mero sprintf().

Answer (score 3):

Outra maneira de resolver isto, seria colocar a TAG [base](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) no cabeçalho de seu site, exemplo:

```
<base href="http://localhost/pasta_raiz/"/>
```

Assim seu link para o *controller* ficaria

```
<a href="apresentacao" title="...">Apresentação</a>
```

Com *action*

```
<a href="apresentacao/acao" title="...">Ação</a>
```

Este método resolve ainda problemas com include de CSS, JS, Imagens e etc...

Comment: Interessante. Isso certamente vai diminuir o comprimentos das linhas do meu HTML